# REACTJS loading and print in Chrome does not show some informations

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, printing

I use REACTJ and when I click the "print" button in Chrome, it reload the view of the screen and one of my component does not appear in print dialog.

I tried to use `beforeprint` and `afterprint` to catch the event, but the problem does not come from the event but the fact : the printing dialog from chrome always refresh the view (get response from API) and it does not get all information but show immediatly the print view.

Comment: What should I do if I don't want to use any personnalize button but print button of Chrome?